# How to start a block scalar with a blank line?

Tags: yaml

When I try and start a block scalar in YAML with a blank line, it complains when it gets to the next line that has the same indentation as the empty line, "syntax error: expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'" (but curiously, not about lines that are further indented). What am I missing here?

Complains (about `done`):

```
            - |

                 export $e
              done
```

Works:

```
            - |
              #   
                  export $e
              done
```

I've tried leaving the spaces out of the first line, adding 4 additional spaces to the first line (so it aligns with `export`), and adding 4 additional spaces and including an indentation indicator (`- |4`), all to no avail.

**Backstory**

This is for an AWS CloudFormation template, and the previous line is part of a !Join and I need a newline before `export $e`. If there are other ways to address this than putting the blank line at the start of the block scalar, that would be fine too, but I'm still curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [block indentation indicator](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793979) to explicitly indicate how much the data is indented. In your case this indentation is two (2): the start of the line with `done` relative to the column in which the item indicator (`-`) is located.

```
        - |2

             export $e
          done
```

Normally the parser calculates the indentation based on the first non space on the first line of the literal (or folded) scalar, if this line has more whitespace that others, or has no non-space text at all, you need to "help" the parser with the block indentation indicator.

Comment: Perfect! I had tried the block indentation indicator, but misunderstood to which point it was indicating.